# WPF black spaces on resize

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, resize

When i create a band new WPF project without changing any code whatsoever does this on resize.

[image: A screenshot]

It stays this way if i minimize or drag across monitors. Is this supposed to happen? It does this with all of my WPF applications so i set  ResizeMode="CanMinimize" .

Thanks

Comment: I've just checked that and wasn't able to reproduce your behaviour. What is your Net Framework version? 3.5 or 4.0 ?

Comment: maybe its time for a new video card? or a directX reinstall?

Comment: its .net 4.0 and it does the same in .net 3.5.

Comment: Can you download some demo WPF application from the internet and verify if it too has the same problem with resizing contents? Also try it as WPF Browser apps and / or silverlight.